# Unknown column in 'where clause' in Update statement

Tags: php, mysql, database

The update statement needs to change the balance of user.

```
update register set bal=(bal-$tax) where name=$user
```

but it is showing the error atUnknown column  in 'where clause'

Table structure:
   name   ||   password   ||   bal
   karan12   karan123    6000
   mitul            5454              9000

Query:
`$q=  mysql_query("update register set bal=(bal-$tax) where name=$user" , $connection) or die("Select Query failed: ".mysql_error());`

Error:

Unknown column 'mitul' in 'where clause'

Comment: Please, show table structure and provide full error message.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @sectus Yup made changes

Answer (score 5):

I think your name column is `Varchar` then you should enclose the `variable $user` into a quotation

```
update register set bal=(bal-$tax) where name='".$user."'
```